# "data not ready yet" message in ArangoDB Web Interface

Tags: arangodb

I'm new at ArangoDB and i installed it on new Ubuntu server.
In the arango web interface i see the message "data not ready yet" all over the main (statistics) page.

What's wrong?

BTW
I also installed Arango on a local windows machine and it's all fine there..

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide more information? ArangoDB Version (compiled?, package?), Ubuntu Version, etc.

Comment: Arango 2.8.7 
Ubuntu 14.04.4 x64

I just follow the instractions here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-arangodb-on-ubuntu-14-04
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just set up an ArangoDB instance (2.8.7) on a t2.medium machine at AWS Cloud with Ubuntu Server (Ubuntu Server 14.04.03 and 14.04.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-87564feb) and followed all of the mentioned tutorial steps (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-arangodb-on-ubuntu-14-04). Unfortunately I cannot reproduce your described behaviour.

Could you please verify that statistics are not disabled? 
Default-Config-Path: /etc/arangodb/arangod.conf

Please add this setting under server (if not present):

[server]

disable-statistics false

Also it could be helpful if you could open the developer console of your browser and post the output here.

Comment: Hi, I hope this is what you expect. thanks

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
5shared Libs.js?version=1463165382913:17 
dygraphs: Can't plot empty data set (sharedLibs.js?version=1463165382913:15:21533)
2
app.js?version=1463165382913:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Comment: Ok, then it seems that the server is not returning any statistics data. Did you verify that statistics are enabled? It is not that comfortable to solve/debug this issue here, maybe you want to join our slack channel? https://slack.arangodb.com .